# Order of destruction and assignment

Tags: c++, c++11, memory

I am working on an `Entity` class which needs to provide access to its data members through setter methods, which check that a value is allowed before storing it (checking code not shown). The `Select` class is one of the types stored and it needs to do some very specific cleaning up when destroyed:

```
#include<memory>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Select {
    int i, j;

    friend class Entity;

public:
    Select(int a, int b) : i{a}, j{b} { }

    ~Select() {
        cout << "destroying " << i << j << endl;
    }

protected:
    Select() { };
};

class Entity {

    Select select_;

public:
    void select_setter(const Select &select) {
        cout << "to be assigned... " << select.i << select.j << endl;
        select_ = select;
    }

    static shared_ptr<Entity> create(const Select &s) {
        auto sp = make_shared<Entity>(Entity{});
        sp->select_setter(s);
        return sp;
    }
};
```

This block demonstrates how I want the `Entity` type to be used:

```
int main() {
    auto sp = Entity::create({1, 1});    
    sp->select_setter({2, 2});
    sp->select_setter({3, 3});    
    cout << "the end" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
destroying 00
to be assigned... 11
destroying 11
to be assigned... 22
destroying 22
to be assigned... 33
destroying 33
the end
destroying 33
```

Why is 33 destroyed twice, but 00, 11 and 22 only once?

Comment: You probably meant to tag this C++11?

Comment: You should be logging the construction (default and copy constructor) in addition to destruction.  That would give you a better idea of what's going on.

Comment: shared_ptr destroys object it points to in the end of the program (in addition to select's normal destructor)

Comment: Within `create`, `Entity{}` creates a temporary `Entity` that in turn contains a default-constructed `Select`. The temporary is destroyed soon afterwards, taking `Select` with it. That causes the first line of output, `destroying 00`

Comment: `{1, 1}`, `{2, 2}` and `{3, 3}` each construct a temporary `Select` which is soon destroyed. This accounts for three more `destroying...` lines. The last line is of course produced when `sp` goes out of scope and destroys `*sp`, and with it `sp->select_` (which at this point holds "33" from the most recent assignment).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik What I don't get is why I don't see {0, 0}, {1, 1} and {2, 2} being destroyed twice. Once for the temporary version, second time for the stored version?

Comment: There's only one "stored" instance of `Select`, inside `Entity` object that `sp` points to. How can a single instance be destroyed three times? Do you expect each assignment to somehow destroy and recreate it?

Comment: By adding more outputs to std::cout, it should be quit obvious to answer this question...

Comment: @IgorTandetnik That was the idea. I thought when I assign a new instance to the existing one in Entity, the existing one is dropped/destroyed.

Comment: Note that the two zero values are showing up by accident: the members are not initialized in `Select()` and are, thus, uninitalized. Since they are next read the result of the program is undefined behavior to start with.

Comment: When you assign to `select_` it uses the `Select` assignment operator (which defaults to just copying values).  The constructors and destructor are not involved at all.

Comment: @DietmarKühl No, the default constructor initializes data members with default values. For `int` data members 0 is the default.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Any way to turn that off?

Comment: What do you mean "turn it off"?  You can delete it (`Select &operator=(const Select &) = delete;`), in which case you'll get an error when you try to assign.  You have an explicit default constructor which explicitly leaves the fields uninitialized.

Comment: @ArneWolframm: where exactly does it do so? If `Select` had no default constructor, yes, value initialization would do so (as the `Entity` object doesn't have a default constructor and gets value initialized which results in value initialization of all subobjects). However, since `Select` has a default constructor members get default initialized which does nothing for builtin types. If you wanted to get value initialization you'd need to write `Select(): i(), j() {}`

Comment: Thanks helping me understand this!

Answer (score 3):

When you want to analyse such constructor/destructor behaviour, my recommendation is to:

- Log **all** constructors (default constructor, copy constructor, additional constructor)
- Log **all** destructors
- Log address of the objects to know who is who...

By adding more outputs, and implementing `Select` and `Entity` copy constructors you can get:

```
Before auto sp = Entity::create({1, 1});
In Select 1 1 ctor 0x7fff85e31b80                    // That's Select temporary object {1,1} being created
In Select default ctor 0x7fff85e31b40                // That's Entity attribute being created before Entity ctor is entered below
In Entity ctor 0x7fff85e31b40                        // That's Entity ctor for Entity{} you create
In Select default ctor 0x2248028                     // That's Entity attribute being created before Entity ctor is entered below
In Entity copy ctor copy 0x7fff85e31b40 to 0x2248028 // That's copying Entity{} object as the shared_ptr attribute
In Entity dtor 0x7fff85e31b40                        // That's Entity{} being destroyed
destroying 00 0x7fff85e31b40                         // That's Entity{}'s Select attribute being destroyed. Is 00 but could be anything else (not initialized)
to be assigned... 11
destroying 11 0x7fff85e31b80                         // That's Select temporary object {1,1} being destroyed

Before sp->select_setter({2, 2});
In Select 2 2 ctor 0x7fff85e31b70                    // That's Select temporary object ({2,2})
to be assigned... 22
destroying 22 0x7fff85e31b70                         // That's Select temporary object ({2,2}) being destroyed

Before sp->select_setter({3, 3});
In Select 3 3 ctor 0x7fff85e31b80                    // That's Select temporary object ({3,3})
to be assigned... 33
destroying 33 0x7fff85e31b80                         // That's Select temporary object ({2,2}) being destroyed

the end
In Entity dtor 0x2248028                             // That's Entity stored in the shared_ptr object being destroyed
destroying 33 0x2248028
```

And this perfectly makes sense...

Simply use this code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Select {
    int i, j;

    friend class Entity;

public:
    Select(int a, int b) : i{a}, j{b} { std::cout << "In Select " << a << " " << b << " ctor" << std::hex << "0x" << this << std::endl;}

    ~Select() {
        cout << "destroying " << i << j << std::hex << "0x" << this << endl;
    }

    Select( const Select& e ) {
        i = e.i; j = e.j;
        std::cout << "In Select copy ctor copy " << std::hex << "0x" << &e << " to " << std::hex << "0x" << this << std::endl;
    }

    Select() { std::cout << "In Select default ctor" << std::hex << "0x" << this << std::endl; }

};

class Entity {

    Select select_;

public:

    Entity() { std::cout << "In Entity ctor " << std::hex << "0x" << this << std::endl; }
    Entity( const Entity& e ) {
         select_ = e.select_;
         std::cout << "In Entity copy ctor copy " << std::hex << "0x" << &e << " to " << std::hex << "0x" << this << std::endl;  }

    ~Entity() { std::cout << "In Entity dtor " << std::hex << "0x" << this << std::endl; }

    void select_setter(const Select &select) {
        cout << "to be assigned... " << select.i << select.j << endl;
        select_ = select;
    }

    static shared_ptr<Entity> create(const Select &s) {
        auto sp = make_shared<Entity>(Entity{});
        sp->select_setter(s);
        return sp;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::cout << "Before auto sp = Entity::create({1, 1});" << std::endl;
    auto sp = Entity::create({1, 1});
    std::cout << "Before sp->select_setter({2, 2});" << std::endl;
    sp->select_setter({2, 2});
    std::cout << "Before sp->select_setter({3, 3});" << std::endl;
    sp->select_setter({3, 3});
    cout << "the end" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```